# Facebooks Big Table Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, bigtable

I found out that facebook use whats called a big table. Is there a way that I can use this "Big table" database in an application that I am using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. The project is called [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/). Facebook just opensourced it. You can download it from [here](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/#download). But be very afraid, because the project is still under highly active development.

If you are going to use it from other language like C#, you also need [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) to talk to cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

All the existing NO SqL databases are following the principle of Big Table, invented by Google.

Not only Facebook, Amazon, IBM, mongo, and some other vendors all provides big table based database systems.